# Two adjoining rectangles tikz in matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm using a matrix to put the nodes in a Tikz diagram:

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, calc}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [
    auto,   
    fblk/.style    = { rectangle, draw=gray, fill=pink!30, text width=4.5em, text centered, minimum height=1em },
    %ffblk/.style    = { rectangle, draw=gray, fill=pink!30, text width=4.5em, text centered,   minimum height=1em },
    ]

    \matrix [column sep=2.3em, row sep=1.em] {
        \node[fblk](f1){FBLK1}; && \node[fblk](f2){FBLK2};\\
        & \node[fblk](f3){FBLK3}; \\
    %    \node[ffblk](f4){FBLK1}{FBLK2}; \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I want define a new node style, `ffblk` that has 2 adjoing rectangles. This node style takes two arguments, each for each rectangles. See the image.

[image]

I tried to manage this by adding `xshift=-...` to the next node; and by making `column sep=0em`. But I could not create what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this, using the `shapes.multipart` library ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fblk/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2, draw, anchor=center, draw=gray, fill=pink!30}]
\node [fblk] {FBLK1\nodepart{two}FBLK2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

When two adjacents nodes in a `matrix` should share a border line, `row sep` and|or `column sep` should be fixed to `-\pgflinewidth`:

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, calc}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [
    auto,   
    fblk/.style    = { rectangle, draw=gray, fill=pink!30, text width=4.5em, text centered, minimum height=1em },
    ]

    \matrix [column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth] {
        \node[fblk](f1){FBLK1}; & \node[fblk](f2){FBLK2};\\
        & \node[fblk](f3){FBLK3}; \\
    %    \node[ffblk](f4){FBLK1}{FBLK2}; \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]